# Prevent google map infowindow to scroll outside of own window

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, custom-scrolling

I have been trying to prevent scrolling the webpage when scrolling inside a infowindow. My infowindow has a scroll-enabled div inside and once it reaches the bottom of the div it scrolls the webpage.

I know how to do it for a normal div using jQuery by changing 'overflow' css style as you can see below.

```
$('.classOfMyDiv').on('mouseover', function(event) {
     $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}
$('.classOfMyDiv').on('mouseout', function(event) {
     $('body').css('overflow', '');
}
```

but it seems it is not working when using a div inside a infowindow. Anyone managed to do it? I also tried using a google listener for the infowindow for mouseover and mouseout events but no luck as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google maps event listeners on both the InfoWindow and the Map to disable body scrolling.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

// This event is fired when the <div> containing the InfoWindow's content is attached to the DOM.
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {

    toggleBodyOverflow('hidden');
});

// This event is fired when the close button was clicked.
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {

    toggleBodyOverflow('auto');
});

// This event is fired when the user clicks on the map (and therefore closes the InfoWindow).
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {

    toggleBodyOverflow('auto');
});
```

Why the map `click` event listener? Because there are two ways to close an InfoWindow: using the close button — or — clicking on the map. As the InfoWindow doesn't have a proper `close` event, you will need to use both.

And the function to toggle the body overflow:

```
function toggleBodyOverflow(param) {
    $('body').css({
        overflow: param
    });
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/d052egde/)</kbd>

Comment: Is it working on your side? Like I said I tried already using listeners but without luck.

Comment: Yes it is working. Did you try that code? I can't tell what you did wrong as you didn't post your code. See added demo in my answer.

Comment: Btw. you mentioned *google listener for the infowindow for mouseover and mouseout events* but the infowindow does **not** have such events: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

Comment: My bad. Your fiddle is not working on my win7 - firefox but ill give it another try back home - im on a work station. However, I think of something that is not going to work as I would like is the fact that if you click on a infowindow and then want to scroll the page it should be allowed. In your exemple its not going to work. Thats why I was trying a mouseover event (which does not exist - thanks about that)